# SQL Server will not divide values properly

Tags: sql-server

I am trying within SQL Server to take the 80th and 50th percentiles of the raw data below, and then divide the 80th by the 50th and call it LOTTR. When I do so the LOTTR values are wrong, as manual calculations are different. I do not know why it is doing this.

```
TMC        Travel_time 
----------------------
113P07005    0.79 
113P07005    0.61 
113P07005    1.31 
113P07005    1.25 
113P07005    1.87 
113P07005    1.31 
113P07005    1.25
```

What code I have thus far:

```
WITH PERCENTILES_LOTTR
AS (
    SELECT TMC_code
        ,EPOCH
        ,percentile_CONT(.80) WITHIN
    GROUP (
            ORDER BY cast(travel_time_minutes AS FLOAT)
            ) OVER (PARTITION BY TMC_code) AS P80
        ,percentile_CONT(.50) WITHIN
    GROUP (
            ORDER BY cast(travel_time_minutes AS FLOAT)
            ) OVER (PARTITION BY TMC_code) AS P50
    FROM [dbo].[I430_2019_nonull_Cars_1_21]
    WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, EPOCH) BETWEEN 6
            AND 7
        AND (
            WKDAY != 'SAT'
            AND WKDAY != 'SUN'
            )
    )
SELECT tmc_code
    ,cast(p80 AS FLOAT) / cast(p50 AS FLOAT) AS LOTTR
FROM percentiles_LOTTR
GROUP BY tmc_code
    ,p80
    ,p50
ORDER BY Tmc_CODE
```

Output results:

[image]

Comment: So, these manual calculations that you're comparing to disagree. How do we know you've computed those right? - you've not shown us those values *at all*.

Comment: One TMC result I get is .73 for the 80th, .65 for the 50th, but the sql output has lottr at 1.089 instead of 1.123.

Comment: Could you toss `p80` and `p50` into your result set (final SELECT statement) and update the results at the top so we can see what the intermediate data looks like?

Comment: Here is a sample output: 

TMC_code P80 TMC_code P50 tmc_code LOTTR
113+04391 0.73 113+04391 0.65 113+04391 1.089552239
113+04392 1.77 113+04392 1.64 113+04392 1.06626506
113+04393 1.2 113+04393 1.12 113+04393 1.052631579
113+04394 0.27 113+04394 0.25 113+04394 1.08
113+04395 0.64 113+04395 0.59 113+04395 1.066666667
113+04396 0.81 113+04396 0.71 113+04396 1.125

Comment: That IS peculiar. I'm trying to imagine a scenario where float imprecision could cause such a wide gap between 1.123 and 1.089.  While it shouldn't make a difference, you can remove that `CAST(... as FLOAT)` bit from your code as the output from `percentile_CONT` is a float.

Comment: Derp derp derp. I was running three scripts in series with three percentiles. The first two just outputted the 80th and 50th, while the third dividing them. The second percentile was wrong in that the where statement was off and looking at only saturday. That explains the math. Derp.